# Detecting if a string is a double or long in C

Tags: c, double, long-integer

I'm dealing with an char[] containing text which should represent a double number value OR a long number.
I'm in a need to write a function that detects which of the above data-types is represented (if any).

I thought about using strtol() and check if it fails to parse the entire string, and if it fails, using strtod().

I would be happy to see whether there is a better option to do so.
Thanks.

Comment: The [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) functions are pretty much the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about using strtol() and check if it fails to parse the entire string, and if it fails, using strtod().

I think that's a good idea and I don't think there is a better one. Implementing your own parsing routine is generally a bad idea.

I would trim the string from trailing whitespace before calling `strtol` to avoid false negatives.

Comment: `strtol()` doesn't care about trailing white space; it leaves it as part of the uninterpreted portion of the string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If there is trailing white space, `strtol` won't parse the entire string, it will stop at the first white space thereby "failing" to parse the entire string, hence false negative.

Answer (score 1):

`strtol()` and `strtod()`  is the right approach.  Be sure to use `errno` to detect integer overflow.  2 stand-alone functions follow:

```
int  Is_long(const char *src, long *dest) {
  char *endptr;
  // Clear, so it may be tested after strtol().
  errno = 0;  
  // Using 0 here allows 0x1234, octal 0123 and decimal 1234. 
  long num = strtol(src, &endptr, 0);
  // If +/- overflow, "" or has trailing text ...
  if (errno || endptr == src || *endptr != '\0') {
    return 0;
  }
  if (dest) *dest = num;
  return 1;
}

int  Is_double(const char *src, double *dest) {
  char *endptr;
  // In this case, detecting over/undeflow IMO is not a concern, so ignore it.
  double num = strtod(src, &endptr);
  // If "" or has trailing text ...
  if (endptr == src || *endptr != '\0') {
    return 0;
  }
  if (dest) *dest = num;
  return 1;
}
```

@Klas Lindbäck does bring up the good point of what to do about trailing white-space.  This answer assumes it is not valid.

Answer (score -2):

```
 You can use the following code to detect that.

 char* isDouble = strchr(string, '.');
 if (isDouble) { 
   // is Double here
 }else {
   // is long here
 }
```

Comment: the problem is that it depends on region so you cannot assume a float always has "." it could be a "," too.

Comment: What about `1E-6`?  No decimal points, but it represents a double.